# How can I create a intent based feature in Microsoft Luis from API?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I want to create intent features (not global) for a Microsoft Luis app. To create features, I send the following message to my app by calling the ***create_list_features*** ([documentation for this call](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5890b47c39e2bb052c5b9bff)) with the following body :

```
{
"name": "DaysOfWeek",
"phrases": "monday,tuesday,wednesday,thursday,friday,saturday,sunday",
"isExchangeable": true
}
```

Unfortunately, in the call, there is no way where I can specify the intent (or intent_id) to assign the feature. Is there any other call that I have to perform for assigning the feature to the intent?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the API reference for [adding intent feature relation](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/luis-programmatic-apis-v3-0-preview/operations/5d9dadbc462b503763684f08). You specify the intent ID as a request parameter and provide the feature relation information in the request body.

```
{
"featureName": "Phraselist1",
"isRequired": false
}
```